# C++ Length Error with bubble sort on a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, bubble-sort

I'm trying to write an implementation of bubble sort that is a template function.

When I test out this algorithm with a regular ol' array, it seems to work just fine. I get the correct output.

However, when I test it with a vector, I get a length_error exception, and I'm not really sure why.

```
template<class T>
void swap_right(T a[], int index)
{
    T temp = a[index];
    a[index] = a[index+1];
    a[index+1] = temp;
}

template<class T>
void bubbleSort(T a[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < (size-i); ++j)
        {
            if(a[j] > a[j+1])
            {
                swap_right(a, j);
            }
        }
    }
}

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v {9, 5, 3, 7, 4, 1};
    bubbleSort(&v, 6);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bubbleSort(v.data(), 6);` You're passing a pointer to the vector itself, not its contents.

Comment: I would suggest having your functions accept a `std::vector<T>&` rather than `T[]`. I would also suggest using `std::swap` instead of a custom version.

Comment: Take a long hard look at this `j+1`. Will it always work? Check for size==1.

Comment: As an aside, I would suggest using iterators - that way you would be able to pass from-to ranges and have them interact easily with other algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

You pass a pointer to the vector, which basically means you try to sort an array of vectors, which is not correct and will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Instead you should pass the *contents* of the vector to the sorting function, using e.g. the [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) member function:

```
bubbleSort(v.data(), v.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having your functions accept a std::vector& rather than T[].

I would also suggest using std::swap instead of a custom version. – Alex Zywicki 3 mins ago   edit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


template<class T>
void bubbleSort(std::vector<T>& a)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(unsigned  j = 0; j < (a.size()-i)-1; ++j)
        {
            if(a[j] > a[j+1])
            {
                std::swap(a[j],a[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v {9, 5, 3, 7, 4, 1};
    bubbleSort(v);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

live demo:http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e22fe55a38425870

result is:

1 3 4 5 7 9

Comment: When `i` is zero, `j` can go up to `a.size()-1`.  You then refer to `a[j+1]` which is off the end.  (This bug is also present in the OP)

Comment: I edited my response in attempt to fix the potential bug